# Apache Spark:How to get parquet output file size and records

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, parquet

I am newbie in apache spark and i want to get parquet output file size.

My Scenario is

Read the file from csv and save as text file

```
myRDD.saveAsTextFile("person.txt")
```

after saved the file spark UI(localhost:4040) showing me inputBytes 15607801 and outputBytes 13551724

but when i save as parquet file

```
myDF.saveAsParquetFile("person.perquet")
```

UI(localhost:4040) on stage tab, only show me inputBytes 15607801 and there is nothing in outputBytes.

Can anybody help me. Thanks in advance

**Edit** 
When I call REST API it giving me following response.

```
[ {
  "status" : "COMPLETE",
  "stageId" : 4,
  "attemptId" : 0,
  "numActiveTasks" : 0,
  "numCompleteTasks" : 1,
  "numFailedTasks" : 0,
  "executorRunTime" : 10955,
  "inputBytes" : 15607801,
  "inputRecords" : 1440721,
  **"outputBytes" : 0,**
  **"outputRecords" : 0,**
  "shuffleReadBytes" : 0,
  "shuffleReadRecords" : 0,
  "shuffleWriteBytes" : 0,
  "shuffleWriteRecords" : 0,
  "memoryBytesSpilled" : 0,
  "diskBytesSpilled" : 0,
  "name" : "saveAsParquetFile at ParquetExample.scala:82",
      "details" : "org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.saveAsParquetFile(DataFrame.scala:1494)\ncom.spark.sql.ParquetExample$.main(ParquetExample.scala:82)\ncom.spark.sql.ParquetExample.main(ParquetExample.scala)",
  "schedulingPool" : "default",
  "accumulatorUpdates" : [ ]
}, {
  "status" : "COMPLETE",
  "stageId" : 3,
  "attemptId" : 0,
  "numActiveTasks" : 0,
  "numCompleteTasks" : 1,
  "numFailedTasks" : 0,
  "executorRunTime" : 2091,
  "inputBytes" : 15607801,
  "inputRecords" : 1440721,
  **"outputBytes" : 13551724,**
  **"outputRecords" : 1200540,**
  "shuffleReadBytes" : 0,
  "shuffleReadRecords" : 0,
  "shuffleWriteBytes" : 0,
  "shuffleWriteRecords" : 0,
  "memoryBytesSpilled" : 0,
  "diskBytesSpilled" : 0,
  "name" : "saveAsTextFile at ParquetExample.scala:77",
      "details" : "org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.saveAsTextFile(RDD.scala:1379)\ncom.spark.sql.ParquetExample$.main(ParquetExample.scala:77)\ncom.spark.sql.ParquetExample.main(ParquetExample.scala)",
  "schedulingPool" : "default",
  "accumulatorUpdates" : [ ]
} ]
```

Comment: Did the application generate `person.perquet` file on HDFS? If so please check if the files has non-zero size?

Comment: @shanmuga thanks for reply ..... No, file size is more than 10MB and I also tried myDF.saveAsParquetFile("hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hadoop/person.parquet") but problem is still same...

Comment: Clarify your probelm, is it that the output file is not being generated or is it that spark UI is not displaying the output size even though the output file is being generated?

Comment: @shanmuga spark UI is not displaying the output size

Comment: @shanmuga I also add REST API response in my question. please help me

Comment: Spark 2.3 shows the output size correctly. But Spark 2.1 does not.